# AWS S3 Cross-account file transfer via Spark: Getting access denied on the transferred objects in the destination bucket

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a use-case where I want to leverage Spark to transfer files between S3 Buckets in 2 different AWS Accounts.

I have Spark running in a different AWS Account (say Account A). I do not have access to this AWS Account.
I have AWS Account B which is holding the source S3 bucket (S3_SOURCE_BUCKET) and AWS Account C that is holding destination S3 bucket (S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET).

I have created an IAM role in Account C (say: CrossAccountRoleC) to read and write from the destination S3 bucket.

I have set up the primary IAM role in Account B (say: CrossAccountRoleB).

- Adding Account A's spark IAM Role in trust entity
- Adding read write permission to S3 buckets in both Account B and Account C
- Adding an inline policy to assume CrossAccountRoleC

Added CrossAccountRoleB as a trusted entity in CrossAccountRoleC

Also added CrossAccountRoleB in the bucket policy in the S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET.

I am using Hadoop's FileUtil.copy to transfer files between the source and destination S3 buckets. While the transfer is happening successfully, I am getting 403 access denied on the copied objects.

When I am specifying `hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")` , I am getting an error that says "The requester is not authorized to perform action [ s3:GetObject, s3:PutObject, or kms:Decrypt ] on resource [ s3 Source or Sink ]" . From the logs, it seems that the operation is failing while writing to the Destination bucket.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you are better off using s3a per-bucket settings and just using a different set of credentials for the different buckets. Not as "pure" as IAM Role games but since nobody understands IAM roles or knows how to debug them, its more likely to work.

(Do not take the fact that the IAM roles aren't working as a personal skill failing. Everyone fears support issues related to them)

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding s3:PutBucketAcl in the Role definition.